# FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap not found in XCode with Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods to add FaceBook and Google platforms to my iOS app in XCode 12. Trying to build, I get the error below.

iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap not found

I've run all the steps to import the pods and they seem to all be in place. In fact, the missing modulemap is here:

..ProjectName/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit

So it appears XCode simply can't locate the file during the build process. I'm definitely opening the workspace created by the Pod install and not the standalone project. Any thoughts on how to make this connection?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I was not. I had to change direction.

Comment: @CYAD, what you mean you had to change direction? Did you find any workaround ?

Comment: I did not find a workaround. For that particular project, I opted not to use FB SDK.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 12 you got the error: FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap not found because you are opening file with extension .xcproject which will causing no dependencies to your projects.

So quit Xcode and open project again by opening file with extension .xcworkspace (beer in mind you should do this while working with React Native)

Then Product > Clean and Product > Build

Cheer!